# How do I import a live template .jar file for React snippets into JetBrains WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I downloaded a live template .jar file from [jinsihou19 ReactSnippets](https://github.com/jinsihou19/ReactSnippets) on GitHub, referred by the [JetBrains Marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10113-react-snippets).

I could not find any documentation on how to install the .jar file on either sites.

Does anyone know how to install this .jar file into WebStorm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install a plugin from a jar, follow the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#install_plugin_from_disk):

> 1. Download the plugin archive (ZIP or JAR).
> 2. Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select Plugins.
> 3. On the Plugins page, click The Settings button and then click Install Plugin from Disk.
> 4. Select the plugin archive file and click OK.
> 5. Click OK to apply the changes and restart the IDE if prompted.

However, it's probably easier to search the marketplace in Webstorm for `React snippets` and click install there, as you'll find the same plugin.